# Drawing 4 cards from a deck, chance of a queen or a king, why is my method wrong?

Tags: probability

**Four cards are dealt off the top of a well-shuffled deck. 
Find the chance that:**

**You get a queen or a king.**

The solution shows $ 1- \frac { \binom {44}{4}}{ \binom {52}{4}}$

I get that in this case it's easier to use compliment rule, however I'm trying another method and I got the following:

$ \binom {4}{1} \cdot\ \frac {4}{52} \cdot\ \frac {48}{51} \cdot\ \frac {47}{50} \cdot\ \frac {46}{49} $  + $ \binom {4}{1} \cdot\ \frac {4}{52} \cdot\ \frac {48}{51} \cdot\ \frac {47}{50} \cdot\ \frac {46}{49} $ - [ ($ \binom {4}{1} \cdot\ \frac {4}{52} \cdot\ \frac {48}{51} \cdot\ \frac {47}{50} \cdot\ \frac {46}{49} $)^2]

My reasoning is P(1 Queen or 1 King) = P(1 Queen) + P(1 King) - P[P(1 queen) x P (1 king)]

The answer that I got is about 0.2499 which is different from the solution obtained from the compliument method, what did I miss here?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you are (i) forgetting that you may get more than one king/queen, (ii) assuming that the events of getting a king and getting a queen are independent.

Comment: You should be computing the probability of selecting at least one queen or at least one king, not exactly one queen or exactly one king.

Comment: @littleO is my equation for getting exactly 1 queen or 1 king correct though? I guess I made a mistake interpreting the question as getting exactly 1 queen or 1 king

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown in this case getting a king or a queen is not independent ? Is it because the "OR" statement? meaning that they can't both happen thus they are mutually exclusive?

Comment: The expression $\binom{4}{1}\cdot \frac{4}{52}\cdot \frac{48}{51}\cdot \frac{47}{50}\cdot\frac{46}{49}$ is indeed the probability of getting exactly one king.  It is also the probability of getting exactly one queen.  The probability of getting exactly one king *and* exactly one queen is not that expression squared however... instead it is $\binom{4}{1,1,2}\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{4}{51}\cdot\frac{44}{50}\cdot\frac{43}{49}$

Comment: @JMoravitz what about probability of getting exactly one king OR exactly one queen, is it P(1 Queen or 1 King) = P(1 Queen) + P(1 King) - P[P(1 queen) x P (1 king)] ?

Comment: You can of course simultaneously have a king and have a queen., so the events are not mutually exclusive and this is not the exclusive or (XOR), but rather the inclusive or (OR).  These are however not independent (*most events aren't*), and so the probability of their intersection is not the product of their respective probabilities.  This could be intuited by the fact that if you have a king, in your hand you have only three chances of getting a queen still, but if you have no king in your hand you instead have four chances of getting a queen, so having a king or not influences chances.

Comment: Remember, $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$ if **and only if** $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  Most events are not independent, and in particular the events you are interested in are not independent.  In the case that they aren't independent, then $Pr(A\cap B)\neq Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.  Something that is true however is $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B\mid A)$

Comment: Looking over your comments again, it seems possible that you have somehow come to believe that all pairs of events are either mutually exclusive or independent.  It is possible for a pair of events to be neither or even both (*though both only occurs when one is empty*).

Comment: @JMoravitz I think I did consider them to be dependent therefore I used the addition rule P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B).  I thought of them as dependent and not mutually exclusive because the question stated "getting a queen OR a king " not getting a queen and a king.

Comment: The "addition rule" as you call it (*more formally known as the inclusion-exclusion principle*) $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$ is true *always*, it is true for mutually exclusive events, it is true for independent events, it is true for events that are both, and it is true for events that are neither.  Your error is in assuming $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$ which is false in this case.  I.e. your error is in saying it is $Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$..  Instead it is $Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A)\times Pr(B\mid A)$ which is not the same thing.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ohhhhh I get it now ! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @InterstellarProbe 's answer, your method of Inclusion and Exclusion should be

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Q\geq 1\cup K\geq 1) &= \mathsf P(Q\geq 1)+\mathsf P(K\geq 1)-\mathsf P(Q\geq 1\cap K\geq 1) 
\\&=\left(\tfrac{\tbinom 41\tbinom {48}3+\tbinom 42\tbinom {48}2+\tbinom 43\tbinom {48}1+\tbinom 44\tbinom {48}0}{\tbinom{52}4}\right)+\mathsf P(K\geq 1)-\mathsf P(Q\geq 1\cap K\geq 1) 
\\ &= \left(1-\tfrac{\tbinom 40\tbinom {48}4}{\tbinom{52}4}\right)+\left(1-\tfrac{\tbinom 40\tbinom {48}4}{\tbinom{52}4}\right)-\left(1-\tfrac{\tbinom 40\tbinom {48}4+\tbinom 40\tbinom {48}4-\tbinom 40\tbinom 40\tbinom {44}4}{\tbinom{52}4}\right) \\ &= 1-\tfrac{\tbinom {44}{4}}{\tbinom{52}4}\end{align}$$

Noting:

- The probability for obtaining particular counts for kings and queens in the same hand are *not independent*, so you cannot multiply the individual probabilities.
- You need to evaluate the probabilities for having *more* than none of the card type, not exactly 1.
- The evaluation is thus made *much harder* by considering kings and queens as seperate categories, rather than considering "the 8 cards which as king-or-queen" as one category.

Comment: oh wow, I didn't know the other was was this complicated

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{\dbinom{8}{1}\dbinom{44}{3}+\dbinom{8}{2}\dbinom{44}{2}+\dbinom{8}{3}\dbinom{44}{1}+\dbinom{8}{4}\dbinom{44}{0}}{\dbinom{52}{4}} = 1-\dfrac{\dbinom{8}{0}\dbinom{44}{4}}{\dbinom{52}{4}}$

Comment: $\checkmark$ To be clear on how this is constructed: That is the probability for obtaining **1,2,3,or 4** cards from the 8 that are king-or-queen, when drawing any 4 cards from the deck of 52.  Which equals the probability for *not* drawing none from them.

Answer (score 1):

If the deal has no Queens and no Kings, the four cards are chosen among the 48 remaining and we have :

$ \binom {52-8}{4} $ posibilities among $ \binom {52}{4} $

If  we get some queens or some kings, we get $1- \frac { \binom {44}{4}}{ \binom {52}{4}}$, the pointed solution.